# Why can't my Ng2 service utilize my class variables in functions?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'll assume this answer super simple but I have a public variable listSports I pass sports to my components via the MapService.

I'd also like to pass it into the public function getMapData that returns an Http get Observable to components however, I can't seem to do so?

```
@Injectable()
export class MapService {

  // list of sports to export
  listSports: string[] = ["baseball", "football", "paddle", "soccer", "boxing", "golf", "hockey",
    "tennis", "volleyball", "skateboard", "kickball", "bowling", "pool", "offroad",
    "running", "hiking", "skating", "dance", "hockey", "yoga", "wrestling", "squash", "swimming", "horseriding", "fishing",
    "handball", "sailing", "shooting", "bike", "hunting", 'archery', 'karting', 'atv', "karting", "kayaking", 'climbing',
    'cricket', 'motorcycle', 'rugby', 'judo', 'scuba', 'barre', 'atv', 'basketball', 'rowing', 'karate', 'mma', 'equestrian', 'gymnastics'
  ];

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  //return event map data from server
  getMapData(chosen?: string[]): Observable<marker.MapMarker[]> {
```

fails here and doesn't pass in the this.listSports variable

```
    let sportChoices: string[] = chosen !== undefined ? chosen : this.listSports;

    // returns all we need to to make google map markers and populate out menus
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/api/events')
      .map((result) => { ....
```

continues til the end

Comment: How are you calling `getMapdata()` from your component? Are you sure that `chosen` is not null, or an empty array, or an empty string instead of just `undefined`?

Comment: chosen is optional. I'm injecting MapService into the component which then calls mapData and subscribes to the output.  Main issue is how to get  data into the getMapData? I assume inject?

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the code where you're calling getMapData()?